# Only the initial frame is being tracked in YOLOv4 with DeepSORT on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolov4, object-tracking

I am currently trying to do object tracking with YOLOv4 and DeepSORT algorithm on Google Colab by utilizing [this repository](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort) from the AIGuysCode.

Previously, everything was fine and the following command was utilized to install tensorflow 2.3.0 in order to run the *save_model.py* file and the rest of the *object_tracker.py* code.

`!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0`

However, currently tensorflow 2.3.0 is not available, and the following error is persistently occurring:

`Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/ ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.3.0`

I attempted to upgrade to tensorFlow 2.5.0 or the most recent version offered by Colab.

However, the issue remains that only the initial frame is being tracked, and the subsequent frames are not being tracked, yielding a zero track.

As a beginner, I would appreciate any assistance, and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The recent default python version in Google Colab is `Python 3.10.11`. You can check yourself using below code:

```
!python --version  #Output: Python 3.10.11
```

As per this TensorFlow [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu), you will not be able to install `Tensorflow version<2.8` on Python 3.10 which only supports to latest Tensorflow versions (between 2.8 to 2.12) (existing default Tensorflow version is 2.12 in Google Colab).

(Please have a look at this build configuration screenshot)
[image]

You can specify any TensorFlow version between 2.8 to 2.12 to install as below code which will be compatible with existing python version 3.10 in Google Colab.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.10   #(restart the kernel)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__       #to check the installed tensorflow version

!pip install --upgrade tensorflow  #to have most recent TF version installed
```